# php code show error even if is not an error

Tags: php, ftp, syntax-error

It shows me the message (echo function) for a statement with error, but i do not find any error, the code works perfect...

```
//pentru multiple upload
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $_FILES['fileMultiple'] ) ; $i++ )
{
   $destination_file = "/public_html/istorie/imagini/" . $_FILES['fileMultiple']['name'][$i];
   $source_file = $_FILES['fileMultiple']['tmp_name'][$i];
//conditie
    if(filesize($_FILES['fileMultiple']['tmp_name'][$i]) > $max_filesize)
     die("The file you attempted to upload ($source_file) <font color='red'>is too large</font>. MAXIM avaible to uploade $max_filesize ");
// upload the file propriu zisa~
    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
     echo "Successfully uploaded<font color='blue'> $destination_file\n </font><br>";
    } else {
     **echo "There was a problem while uploading $destination_file\n "**;
    }
}
```

When i upload some images, is give me the the echo message `Successfully uploaded bla bla` for each image - is corect, is not?
But at the end shows also the echo, message for error `ftp_put` ... `There was a problem while uploading`
The upload works perfectly... but why is show me the error message even if are not ant errors?

Comment: Are you sure all files are uploaded? Even the last one?

Comment: yes I am, i looked at the fiezilla, and there were all the files

Comment: If you're getting just one line of error, then perhaps your loop is bigger than the amount of files you're trying to upload. Try `for ($i = 1 ; $i < count( $_FILES['fileMultiple'] ); $i++ )` and see if you're still getting all files uploaded.

Comment: I changed puting ``['name']`` at the end of the ```count ( $_FILES['fileMutiple'])``, and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count of `$_FILES['fileMultiple']` is being used in the for loop but with many file uploads, another array should be looped over.

Perhaps  `$_FILES['fileMultiple']['name']` ?

Comment: I modificied and now, it works, does not show me the error message, and the files still uploading all. Thank you, I change `for( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $_FILES['fileMultiple'] ) ; $i++ )` with `for( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $_FILES['fileMultiple']['name'] ) ; $i++ )`